# Android - Passing a search to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have an app that has tabs (4) that each have their own layout and class files. I also have a searchview widget in the actionbar.

What I am attempting to do is allow the user to search for something, get that as a string and then send it to the fragment so I can then use that string and update the UI after using it for a query.

Currently I have it so that the user enters in the text, a class handles the intent and so on a so forth, and then I get that variable in the fragment class that I need it in.

However, when I enter in something to the searchview and hit enter, a new window pops up but with a blank screen. No tabs. No searchview.

Surely I am doing something wrong. Does anyone have an suggestions or a change that I can make?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Home", "Most Recent", "Followed", "All Items" };

    public String test = "test";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) 
        {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
            {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
    {

    }

}
```

SearchResultsActivity.java

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity
{
    public String query = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    }
}
```

companyFragment.java

```
public class companyFragment extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company, container, false);

        String temp = new SearchResultsActivity().query;

        TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(temp);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Paste some relevant code.

Comment: @Grzegorz Added. Let me know if you need more (like XML,etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a basic search example awhile back.
Hopefully this should put you in the right direction.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.AbstractCursor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SearchActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) | true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(this));
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) | true;
    }

    public static class SearchSuggestionsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        private static final String[] mFields = {"_id", "result"};
        private static final String[] mVisible = {"result"};
        private static final int[] mViewIds = {android.R.id.text1};


        public SearchSuggestionsAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, mVisible, mViewIds, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            return new SuggestionsCursor(constraint);
        }

        private static class SuggestionsCursor extends AbstractCursor {
            private ArrayList<String> mResults;

            public SuggestionsCursor(CharSequence constraint) {
                final int count = 100;
                mResults = new ArrayList<String>(count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mResults.add("Result " + (i + 1));
                }
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                    String constraintString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                    Iterator<String> iter = mResults.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        if (!iter.next().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).startsWith(constraintString)) {
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mResults.size();
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getColumnNames() {
                return mFields;
            }

            @Override
            public long getLong(int column) {
                if (column == 0) {
                    return mPos;
                }
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public String getString(int column) {
                if (column == 1) {
                    return mResults.get(mPos);
                }
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public short getShort(int column) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public int getInt(int column) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public float getFloat(int column) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public double getDouble(int column) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimplemented");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isNull(int column) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5514856